# How to generate random positive real number in Julia?

Tags: math, random, julia

I wanna fill my array in Julia by positive real numbers. But I found information only how to do it with integers or real numbers (including negatives). Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: The basic [`rand()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand) does just that in the range `[0, 1)`. Do you want something different, e..g values in the `[0, +∞]` range?

Comment: Yes, I need bigger then 1

Comment: [0, +inf) - yes

Comment: You missed specifying one fundamental information in your question: from which distributions your random numbers should arise from. When this is not specified, one assume a uniform distribution, but clearly `rand(Uniform(0,Inf))` doesn't make sense (try it!). You should first choose a suitable distribution (using the `Distributions.jl` package) and then sample from it using the syntax shown above.

Comment: Maybe you get an *uniform distribution* until the largest float with `rand() * floatmax(Float64)` or with `using Distributions; rand(Uniform(0, floatmax(Float64)))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any mathematical formula that maps the `[0, 1)` range  into the `[0, +inf]`:

For example, if `x` is your random variable in the `[0, 1)` range (obtained with e.g. `rand()` for float data types):

- `tan(x * pi / 2)`
- `atanh(x)`
- `log(x) ^ 2`
- `-log(x) / x ^ p` (for `p` non-negative integer -- it will change the number distribution)

There are many other functions.

Of course the numbers are no longer uniformly distributed, but that is impossible to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, that's good idea. But I was wondering if there is a way to just fill my matrix with random float > 0 in one row. So, the only way to make it it is creating function such as you described and then iterate my matrix calling the function?

Comment: You can use broadcasting, no need to iterate explicitly. For example if `x = rand(Float64, 100)` is your random array, you can write simply `tan.(x * pi / 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the built-in `randexp` fulfils your requirement: the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) has the positive reals as its support.  The scale of the numbers you practically get is much lower, though.  The same holds for `abs ∘ randn`, the half-normal distribution.  (In both cases, you could multiply the results with a large positive number to increase the variance to your requirements.)

Here's a funny alternative: you can generate uniformly random *bits*, and reinterpret them as floats (and just set the sign always to positive):

```
julia> bitrand(3*64).chunks
3-element Vector{UInt64}:
 0xe7c7c52703987e68
 0xc221b9864e7bab7e
 0xa45b39faa65b446e

julia> reinterpret(Float64, bitrand(3*64).chunks)
3-element reinterpret(Float64, ::Vector{UInt64}):
  2.8135484124856866e-108
 -4.521596431965459e53
 -5.836451011310255e78

julia> abs.(reinterpret(Float64, bitrand(3*64).chunks))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.6467305137006711e236
 3.3503597018864875e-260
 1.2211675821672628e77

julia> bitstring.(abs.(reinterpret(Float64, bitrand(3*64).chunks)))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "0000110000011000001110000110001111010000011110111101000101101101"
 "0011000010110101111100111011110100111100011011000101001100010011"
 "0110111000001000101011010100011011010010100111111011001000001100"
```

This is still not a uniform distribution on the values, though, as the precision of floats gets smaller the larger the exponent gets.

Comment: Interesting solution with bits :)